# XCUITest get/trace all UI Interactions done with the Application

Tags: ios, xcode

I have written some UI Tests using `XCTest` Framework of Apple.

While running the tests there certain interactions which are printed on the console logs and which are also stored in `TestSummaries.plist` in Derived Data.

Is there a way to have access to all the interactions during runtime within the `XCTestObservations` or somewhere else?

The summary I am talking about usually looks like the following:

```
t =    13.42s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for an app with pid 11283
t =    13.44s             Find: Descendants matching type Alert
t =    13.44s             Find: Identity Binding
t =    13.44s             Find: Descendants matching type Button
t =    13.44s             Find: Elements matching predicate 'userTestingAttributes CONTAINS "cancel-button"'
t =    13.45s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 11283
t =    13.47s             Find: Descendants matching type Alert
t =    13.47s             Find: Identity Binding
t =    13.47s             Find: Descendants matching type Button
t =    13.47s             Find: Elements matching predicate 'userTestingAttributes CONTAINS "cancel-button"'
t =    13.47s             Tap Button
t =    13.47s                 Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
t =    13.52s                 Find the Button
t =    13.52s                     Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 11283
t =    13.54s                     Find: Descendants matching type Alert
t =    13.54s                     Find: Identity Binding
t =    13.54s                     Find: Descendants matching type Button
t =    13.54s                     Find: Elements matching predicate 'userTestingAttributes CONTAINS "cancel-button"'
t =    13.65s                     Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
t =    13.70s                 Synthesize event
t =    13.80s                 Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
t =    13.86s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 11283
t =    13.87s             Find: Descendants matching type Alert
```